# Why does the curve plot like a linear equation? It should have been plotted like a curve but it's not

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

As you can see the in the image when I try to plot the curve it plots this strange linear structure. All I want is to plot a curve passing through all points as accurately as possible.
[image]

Here is the source code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x =  [0, 7,  9.056,  9.87,  10,    10,    10,    10,    10,  ]
y = [0, 0, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7]

curve = np.polyfit(x, y, 5)
poly = np.poly1d(curve)

plt.plot(x, poly(x))
plt.scatter(x, y)
print(poly)
```

Comment: Because you evaluate `poly()` only at these discreet points. If you plotted the full range of x-values, you would see what the error message also tells you - `RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned`

Comment: Yes ı got the rankwarning message. i dont get it at lower ranks but grah is still wrong. So how can ı make it look like an actual curve? ı am new to python.

Comment: Please see the link. Create `x_fit` with `np.linspace`, then `plt.plot(x_fit, poly(x_fit))` instead of `plt.plot(x, poly(x))`. This solves the plotting problem, not the fitting problem.